# NaN value in Ubuntu but not in Fedora

Tags: c, ubuntu, fedora, nan

I have code in C that get as result a `NaN` in Ubuntu but `8000` (correct value) in Fedora.

```
ExtCurStyle->exts_sideCoupleHalo = (int)(1000 * (float)atof(argv[1]));
```

`argv[1]` is `8`,and I have established through several tries that `atof(argv[1])` is
value `8.0` (double).  However, when I multiply by `1000`, it becomes `NaN`.

What should I do?

Comment: No need to cast the return value of `atof`, just cast the result of the whole operation.

Comment: And is it the result of `1000 * atof(argv[1])` that becomes `NaN`, or is it the `ExtCurStyle->exts_sideCoupleHalo` that is `NaN`? If it is the latter, then are you sure you `ExtCurStyle` is a proper pointer?

Comment: Perhaps you forgot `#include <stdlib.h>`.

Comment: If it is like R.. says, and you forgot to include the required header file, then you could do like this instead: `ExtCurStyle->exts_sideCoupleHalo = (int)(1000.0 * atof(argv[1]));` Note the use of floating-point `1000.0` and no casting for the return of `atof`. If the header file is missing, there will be no prototype for `atof` and the compiler should issue a warning about implicit casting of `int` to `double`.

Comment: So, what else differs between your two machines? Is the same machine running both Ubuntu and Fedora? If it is not, then are there differences between the two processors? Are you compiling the code with the same compiler that has the same version?

Comment: The #include <stdlib.h> is already in the code.